# Where did all of my comments from 9/12/2020 go?

Tags: discussion

re: [expand OS partition backwards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274622/expand-os-partition-backwards/1274696#1274696)

ALL of my comments from 9/12/2020 , and all of the comments from the OP to me, on this question, have disappeared!

Anybody know where/how they disappeared?

Answer (score 7):

Your comments (And OP's comments) have been flagged by users (as no longer needed I assume) and have been removed by moderators.

It's just a typical process of cleaning up questions. Nothing weird has happened here.

*You should use chat-rooms for discussions.* Comments are for asking more details and clarification. *If it's getting into a long discussions* you should *continue it in chats* to keep comment section clean.

---

[Why must we “avoid discussions in comments”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95937/why-must-we-avoid-discussions-in-comments)

Comment: In 10 years on AU, I've never had ALL comments between OP and myself been flagged and deleted.

Comment: It's the moderator who decides what comment should be deleted and which one is useful and should be left untouched. From what I can see, a lot of comments have been flagged, both by users and  automatically by system. You can wait and see if the moderator who deleted you comments would come and answer you. But it does not change the fact that comment section should not be used for discussions. Take this answer for example. As soon as you get your answer I would come back and clean everything up.